# Select from solicitud where fecha

Tags: select

como hacer un select desde mi tabla solicitud con campo fecha donde la fecha es con date=("Y-m-d) seleccionar solo el mes y mostrarlo en un td

Comment: Hola y bienvenida a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [editar](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Para bucar por el mes puedes usar la función extract, siempre y cuando tu fecha sea de tipo DateTime, si fuese de tipo String podrías usar la funcion `SUBSTR(str, position, [length])`, saludos

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "2017-06-15");
```

Comment: Hola @Rafael Valls. Gracias por responder, pero esta pregunta no cumple con las reglas de lo que que es aceptado en el sitio. Para conservar la calidad del mismo se debe evitar responder dichas preguntas. Saludos!